# MDTextField line looks weird until screen is resized

Tags: kivy, uitextfield, textfield, kivymd

I have a series of MDTextFields in my kv file that work, however upon launching my app there is a weird line in the middle of the field that disappears when the window/screen is resized:

[image: before resize]
[image: after resize]

if I do not resize the window then the line persists across all of my screens.

here is my kv code for the screens and one of my textfields:

````
WindowManager:
    transition: NoTransition()
    StartWindow:
        id: start
    SecondWindow:
        id: oob
    SlpQualWindow:
        id: slpql
    DreamsWindow:
        id: dreams
    TagsWindow:
        id: tags
    BedTimeWindow:
        id: bedtime

<StartWindow>:
    name: "start"
    MDLabel:
        text: "Good morning Emily!"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.62}
        halign: 'center'
        font_size: self.width/20
        color: (0,.5,.75,1)

    MDLabel:
        text: "What time did you wake up this morning?"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .56}
        halign: 'center'
        font_size: self.width/30
        color: (0,.5,.75,1)

    MDTextField:
        id: input
        multiline: False
        focus: True
        size_hint_x: 0.2
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        on_text_validate: app.root.current = "oob"

    MDIconButton:
        id: check_btn
        icon: "checkbox-marked-circle"
        pos_hint: {'x': .61, 'top': .525}
        size_hint: (.05, .05)
        theme_icon_color: "Custom"
        icon_color: (0,.5,.75,1)
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "oob"```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try using a fixed size for the TextField.  Remember to set the size_hint to None, None.